# virtual functions, when to use them?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have two classes `Animal` and `Dog` while The latter inherits `Animal`.

So running the following code:

```
Dog* d = new Dog(3,4);
Animal* a = d;
a->makeSound();// Will run Animal.makeSound()
d->makeSound();// Will run Dog.makesound()
```

In order to run `Dog.makesound()` I need to declare `Animal.makeSound()` as `virtual`. But should I do that for every function in `Animal`?
I don't understand when a function should be virtual and when not...

Comment: you should declare virtual in  each function you want to have a different behaviour in child classes.

Comment: is `a->makeSound()` going to run Animal's one? (just curious, coming from Java background where the called method depends on the object type rather than pointer type)

Comment: @Moia, Thanks kindly post as answer

Comment: @mangusta yes it will :-)

Comment: @mangusta in Java is like all methods were declared as `virtual`; in C++ that behavior is opt-in (essentially because "you don't pay what you don't use" and to allow standard-layout classes).

Comment: @Robert don't mind, I wrote there because is not enough complete to be an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand when a function should be virtual and when not...

So think of `Animal` as base class and `Dog` and `Cat` etc. are derived classes from `Animal`. Dog and Cat can all `makeSound()` but clearly their sound are different. So a typical Object Oriented design is to make `Animal` as base class and `makeSound()` a (pure) virtual function - which means each of the derive class will need to implement that function with its own implementation.

On the other hand, functions specific to each class should not be virtual. A (bad) example such as the `Dog` class having a `Bark` function. That function is specific to `Dog` and therefore should not be virtual.

Other usages of `virtual` can be a bit more complicated. Like pure virtual vs. virtual, and virtual destructor. You should read a textbook instead.